# Why are my shapes not added to the stage?

Tags: html, easeljs, createjs

I am drawing a line using CreateJS. As long as it is  the "CreateJS 2013.09.25" reference. The line is drawn like expected.

I was using this so far:

`<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script>`

The problem is with this reference the line is not drawn at all, different than all other shapes which are drawn fine. Here is my code for drawing a line:

```
function CreateLine(x,y,length) {
    var line = new createjs.Shape();
    line.graphics.moveTo(x, y).setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#003300").lineTo(x + length, y);
    stage.addChild(line);
}  
//After that I do update the stage!
```

Is the src I was using so far not the newer one? Why is that?

Comment: Wild guess would be that the API might have changed or something like that, look into the releases note or the documentation of that version to see if the code that draw that line has been modified. There must be quite a difference between a 2013 and 2015 version.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Ok, can you post the snippet of code in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. I'm not sure if it is by design now but the moveTo needs to be called after setting the stroke style and beginning the stroke.

```
line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#003300").moveTo(x, y).lineTo(x + length, y);
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/1jqf2zL7/2/)